# Vuejs route based on payload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Im using vuerouter and want to route to a component based on payload.

```
{
  path: '/foobar',
  name: 'foobar',
  component: foobar,
}
{
  path: '/foobar',
  name: 'foobarSuccess',
  component: foobarSuccess,
  query: { status: 'success' }
}
```

Example above, first route is step one. We do some stuff there then we go to another page and get redirected back with the payload status=succcess. How do i use the query object to route to the correct component?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your router with parameters

```
{
  path: '/foobar',
  name: 'foobar',
  component: foobar,
}
{
  path: '/foobar/:status',
  name: 'foobarSuccess',
  component: foobarSuccess,
  query: { status: 'success' }
}
```

here `status` will contain like `success`, finally `/foobar/success`
based on this parameter also you can display the sccuess message

For more information you can refer the simple docs https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html ,